# When overriding method X, will a call to X from an inherited method use the overriding or the overridden implementation of X?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have this two java classes with this methods:

```
class A {
    void m1 () {
        ...
    }

    void m2 () {
        ...
        m1();
        ...
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Ovveride
    void m1() {
        ...
    }

    void m3() {
        m2();
    }
}
```

What I'm not sure is if the `m1()` called inside `m2()` called inside `m3()` is the new implementation defined inside B or the one in A.

I would wish to call the `m2()` method defined in A BUT using the `m1()` implementation defined in B. My code is correct?

Comment: Does your code compile and run correctly?

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself? Debug it or add some print statements.

Comment: @AndréStannek you're right, I usually would do it, but the problem is that what I have written is (obviously) pseudo-code, and change the real one would create a lot of work to do, and (more important) the error generated by an incorrect use of this particular code could be really hard to detect and debug. However, I created a new project, made this example in a simpler way and checked that it worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what will happen. Class B overrides method m1 and inherits m2. Inside m2 there is a call to m1 *on the current object*. (Remeber: "m1();" is short for "this.m1();".) Since m1 is overridden on instances of B, the overridden method will be called.

But don't take my word for it, try it yourself! Putting in one or two simple `System.out.println`s will prove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried by myself with some toy-project and checked that it worked correctly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but pay attention to the following:

1. First of all you didn't specify exposure level (private, protected etc.), in that case your method default exposure level is "package protected".
2. you need to instantiate B in order to use it's override methods:

   A obj = new B();
   obj.m3();

Now your m1 method of obj will actually linked to B.m1()

Answer (score 0):

Class A:

```
public class A {
public void m1(){
    System.out.println("Method1 from class A");
}
public void m2(){
    System.out.println("Method2 from class A");
    m1();
}
```

}

Class B:

```
public class B extends A{
@Override
public void m1(){
    System.out.println("Method1 from class B");
}
public void m3(){
    m2();
}
```

}

Main :

```
public class TestAB {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a=new A();
    B b=new B();
    a.m1();a.m2();
    System.out.println();
    b.m1();
    b.m3();
}
```

}

Result:

Method1 from class A
Method2 from class A
Method1 from class A

Method1 from class B
Method2 from class A
Method1 from class B